# WiX: FileSource confusion

Tags: wix

Just trying to setup an installer for the first time, bit confusing.

This code;

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="FTSM" Name="FTSM">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="FCP" FileSource="..\FCP\bin\Debug\">
                <Component Id="MainExecutable">
                    <File Id="FCPEXE" Name="FCP.exe" Source="FCP.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
                    <Shortcut Id="startMenuFCP" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="FCP" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="FCP.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes"/>
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Doesn't give me any success, I always get `System cannot find the file 'FCP.exe'`
If I take the FileSource variable and put it into the source variable, like so;

```
<File Id="FCPEXE" Name="FCP.exe" Source="..\FCP\bin\Debug\FCP.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
```

Then everything works perfectly. I can build the WiX project without errors and it generates an installer that works as expected.

The file structure is as follows;

```
Main
-> FCP (Main Project)
--> bin
---> Debug
----> FCP.exe
-> Installer (WiX Project)
--> Product.wxs
```

Obviously not a big issue for this Project, but when I run into multiple components, it's going to be a lot handier to specify the FileSource once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a bit of a lucky find really, but it turns out if you use the references folder from within the WiX project you can then do some neat referencing in the wxs file.

I referenced my project and could then do the following;

```
<File Id="FCPEXE" Name="FCP.exe" Source="$(var.FCP.TargetDir)\FCP.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Bob Arnson's blog-entry [Choosing your payloads](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2009/01/01/choosing-your-payloads/):

> **When you use the `File/@Name`** attribute **and don’t use the `File/@Source`
>   attribute**, the compiler constructs an implicit path to the file based
>   on the file’s parent component directory plus the name you supply.

Thus when `File/@Source` is present WiX will use it regardless of any `Directory/@FileSource`, if it is not then the source path is constructed by combining `Directory/@FileSource` and `File/@Name`.